# Fade background on mouseleave and unfade on mouseenter. jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to unfade the background when I enter the mouse on my webpage but it doesn't seem to work. I've tried looking around on here for a similar solution but unable to do so.

jQuery:

```
//fade
$("html").mouseleave(function(){
        $('#intro').fadeTo('slow',0.33,function(){
                    $("#intro").css("background");
        });
});
//unfade

$("html").mouseenter(function(){
        $('#intro').fadeTo('slow',1,function(){
                    $("#intro").css("background");
        });
});
```

Fading works perfectly, but the unfading part is what i'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual fade works fine. The issue will be because of the syntax error here:

`$("#intro").css({background});`

You are using object notation but havent passed a valid object (key, value). If it is supposed to be a variable then remove the braces, or give the property `background` a value if it is supposed to be an object.

```js
$("html").mouseleave(function(){
        $('#intro').fadeTo('slow',0.33,function(){
        $("#intro").css({background: 'green'});
        });
});

$("html").mouseenter(function(){
        $('#intro').fadeTo('slow',1,function(){
        $("#intro").css({background: 'red'});
        });
});
```

```css
#intro {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="intro">
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah i removed the url in the question, forgot to remove {}. Still doesn't work tho.

Comment: I added the code snippet to my answer and, as you can see, the fade works fine so there must be another issue. Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: yeah, for some reason i cannot target my css-image with jquery. it's located in my cssfile like this: #intro{background:url....}. Any ideas on how to target this?